# How to abort Jenkins job if any parallel step throw an error without waiting for execution of other steps in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have multiple executors in Stage while, I wanted to abort as soon as anyone of the steps executing is having an error, with which I will not wait till the other parallel executors are finished.

This is important for me since each step takes quite a time to completely execute, while at the end Job is Failed. In short I am planning to reduce execution time of a pipeline significantly.

I have a sample declarative pipeline below with only 2 executors group1 and group2:

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
           stage ('Parallel Stage') {
              steps {
                 parallel (
                    'group1': {
                         sleep 10
                         echo 'Completed step1'
                    },
                    'group2': {
                         sleep 5
                         error 'Error in step2'
                    },
                )//parallel
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `failFast` option with the keyword `parallel`

Syntax is:

```
FailFast: true //if you want to abort stage with any step execution has error i.e. quick abort on error detection without waiting for execution of other steps.
FailFast: false // if you want to still execute all other steps after detection of first error in step.
```

Two different workflow based on `failFast` value, shown below.

**Pipeline1:**

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
           stage ('Parallel') {
              steps {
                 parallel (
                    'group1': {
                        timestamps {
                           catchError {
                              sleep 10
                              echo 'Completed group1 processing'
                           }
                        } 
                     },
                     'group2': {
                         sleep 5
                         error 'Error in group2 processing'
                     },
                    failFast: true 
                 )
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Due to `catchError`user will get interrupt indication generated by `failFast`.
When we run this pipeline, we will get output like that shown below

[image: failFast TRUE]

After 5 seconds sleep the exception get caught in `group1`, because after 5 seconds `group2` threw an error. And then failFast operation terminated `group1`

**Pipeline2:**

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
           stage ('Parallel') {
              steps {
                 parallel (
                    'group1': {
                        timestamps {
                           catchError {
                              sleep 10
                              echo 'Completed group1 processing'
                           }
                        } 
                     },
                     'group2': {
                         sleep 5
                         error 'Error in group2 processing'
                     },
                    failFast: false 
                 )
             }
         }
     }
}
```

If we were to take the `failFast` option out or set it to false, then we would still see the group2 branch terminate with the error, but the group1 branch would run to completion after the 10-second sleep.

[image: failFast False]

With `failFast:true` i.e. in `Pipeline1` you will save time used by `group1`.

Comment: Should have been marked as the accepted answer. That would help community to refer to the post with confidence.